# Vue-typescript error with webpack alias, path not found

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have a problem configuring webpack alias on a vue project with typescript. The same issue is not faced if I'm using normal javascript, hence my confusion

The project is divided in 2, "app_marketplace", "app_producer" (which is like the admin), I also have a 3rd folder for shared components and utilities.

Project folder structure:

- .env.marketplace
- .env.producer
- public/
- src/

  - app_marketplace/
  - app_producer/
  - app_shared/
- vue.config.js
- tslint files, babel, package.json, etc..

I run the 2 app separately from the script in the `package.json`.

For instance, `"serve:marketplace": "vue-cli-service serve --mode marketplace src/app_marketplace/main.ts"` calls my `.env.marketplace` file and sets the `env` to `VUE_APP_MARKETPLACE=true`

Now, in my `vue.config.js` I'm making use of the env variable to set the aliases.

```
configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app_shared'),
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, process.env.VUE_APP_MARKETPLACE ? 'src/app_marketplace' : 'src/app_producer')
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that a lot of the imports don't work or give me error, starting from my `main.ts` inside `app_marketplace`. Another thing I can't explain is why some of them work and some don't.

```
import App from './App.vue'
import router from '~/router' // ERROR
import store from '@/store' // ERROR
import '@/plugins'
import '~/directives'
import { DEBUG } from '~/const/debug' // ERROR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `tsconfig.json` should have a `paths` config that matches your Webpack path aliases:

```
{
  "paths": {
    "~/*": [
      "src/app_shared/*",
    ],
    "@/*": [
      "src/*"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Since the file is JSON, you won't be able to do conditional path aliases in the file.

Comment: is there an issue in having: `"@/*": [
                "src/app_marketplace/*",
                "src/app_producer/*"
            ]`?

Comment: There shouldn't be issue doing that unless you have identical directory trees under both dirs (e.g., `src/app_marketplace/foo/foo.ts` and `src/app_producer/foo/foo.ts`, in which case the first found path takes precedence).