# Typescript tsconfig.json "paths" not found, even when baseUrl is set

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, vuejs3

I have an ionic 7 Vue project in typescript.  I am trying to create an alias for some shared interfaces using tsconfig.json paths, but the added path doesn't resolve.  Here is my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": ["webpack-env", "jest", "google.maps", "cypress"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],//  <-------------------------------- This alias resolves fine.
      "@shared/*": ["../server/src/*/shared/index.ts"] // <- This one doesn't.
      // "@shared/*": ["../server/src/*/shared"] // <------- This also doesn't work (same error).
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    // mp035 added
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "../server/src/**/shared/*.ts" // <----------------- these files are found fine.
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

When building the error I get is:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@shared/bookings' in '/XXXXXX/XXXXX/app/src/views/customer'
```

Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Have you tried `"@shared/*": ["../server/src/*/shared/*"]` or `"@shared": ["../server/src/*/shared/index.ts"]` ?

Comment: if you only set the config in tsconfig.json it won't work, you should also set the config of Webpack or vite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of digging and researching, as @Yu-Miao mentioned I need to also configure webpack to respect the paths.  The option I chose was to use  tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68651785/5434939

For that to work, I installed the plugin with:

```
npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin
```

and then I created a vue.config.js file in the root of my project with the following content

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({extensions:['.ts', '.tsx', '.vue']})]
        }
    }
}
```

**AN ALTERNATIVE FOR THOSE WHO DON'T WANT TO USE A PLUGIN** would have been to reorganize my source files to allow a simpler tsconfig path like `"@shared/*" : "../server/src/shared/*"`. I could then have just used a manual entry in vue.config.js like so:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias:{
                "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                "@shared": path.resolve(__dirname, "../server/src/shared"),
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I however, much prefer the DRY option of the plugin.